# Undefined reference to function CMake

Tags: c++, build, linker, cmake

I am trying to learn CMake, but I get a undefined reference to ... linker error
I have a directory with a subdirectory.
each of them has its own CMakeLists.txt

```
test
|----main.cpp
|----CMakeLists.txt
|----test2
     |----foo.hpp
     |----foo.cpp
     |----CMakeLists.txt
```

the CMakeLists.txt for test is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(tests)

add_subdirectory(test2)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(tests ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

the CMakeLists.txt for test2 is:

```
set(test2_files
        foo.cpp
        foo.hpp
        )
add_library(test2 ${test2_files})
```

`foo.cpp` implements a function which is defined in `foo.hpp`
for this function I am getting the undefined reference error.
What am I doing wrong? How can I get rid of this linker error

EDIT: My CMakeLists.txt now looks like this, but I still get the linker error:

```
project(tests)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

include_directories(test2)
link_directories(test2)

add_subdirectory(test)

add_executable( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES} )

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} test2)
```

I also tried it with the absolute path instead of `test2`

EDIT:
solved it it was only a typo in the CMakeLists.txt of test2.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure that your test `CMakeLists.txt` links to the created library.

```
project(test)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

include_directories( test2 )

#here
link_directories(test2)

add_subdirectory(test2)

add_executable( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES} )

#and here
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} test2 )
```

Comment: If I am using this I am getting this error: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltest2`

Comment: Added a line, give the top level a local for link directories.

Comment: Do you want it to be *.a or *.so? This implemenation generates a *.a file in the build directory.

Comment: i tried it with link_directories(test2) also with absolute paths but it keep saying "udefined reference to..."

Comment: @Exagon. Did you get it working? Sorry, I've been away from computer for a couple days.

Answer (score 4):

Function `add_subdirectory($dir)` does not automatically add `$dir` to include directories and link directories. To use library `test2` you should do it manually in CMakeLists.txt of `test` directory:

```
include_directories(test2/)
link_directories(test2/)
```

Then, link your executable with `test2` library to get functions definitions. Add to CMakeLists.txt of `test` directory:

```
target_link_libraries(tests test2)
```