# When using cmake with C++ project an "undefined reference" error occures

Tags: c++, build, cmake, linker

My project has the following structure:

```
-project
|- main.cpp
|- CMakeLists.txt
|- Headers
    |- animal.cpp
    |- animal.hpp
    |- lives.cpp
    |- lives.hpp
    |- CMakeLists.txt
```

We further have:

```
#/project/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

project(main)

include_directories(Headers/)
link_directories(Headers/)
add_subdirectory(Headers)

add_executable(main main.cpp Headers/animal.cpp Headers/lives.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main animal_lib)
target_link_libraries(main genome_lib)
```

as well as

```
#/project/Headers/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(lives_lib STATIC lives.cpp lives.hpp)
add_library(animal_lib STATIC animal.cpp animal.hpp)

target_include_directories(lives_lib PUBLIC ./)
target_include_directories(animal_lib PUBLIC ./)
```

Note also that `animal.cpp` includes `lives.hpp`. When I try to run cmake I get an linking error (`undefined reference`). If I a remove `animal.cpp` and `animal.hpp` (and all the functions that depend on it, so only things from `lives.cpp` are used) everything runs fine. Is the problem that I'm using function from `lives.hpp` in `animal.cpp` and if so, how do I fix this.

---

**Note:** I tried a couple of thins, mostly the suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38530491/undefined-reference-to-function-cmake). But it still doesn't link correctly.

---

Error message:

```
$ make
[ 33%] Built target animal_lib
Scanning dependencies of target genome_lib
[ 55%] Built target lives_lib
[ 66%] Linking CXX executable main
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/main.dir/Headers/animal.cpp.o: in function `Animal::set_something(double)':
animal.cpp:(.text+0x53): undefined reference to `Animal::something_else_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make:118: main] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:77: CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Do I understand you correct that `animal_lib` makes use of `lives.cpp` and `lives.hpp`? In that case you need to include them for `animal_lib` or make it link against `lives_lib`.

Comment: @super yes, you understand correctly. What exactly do you mean with "include them" or link?

Comment: I've never tried building one static lib from other static libs, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50022318/using-cmake-to-build-a-static-library-of-static-libraries) suggests it can be done. However, my thought is why is it not `add_library(animal_lib STATIC animal.cpp animal.hpp lives.cpp lives.hpp)` since they are part of `animal_lib`.

Comment: @super I just tried your suggestion, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: "When I try to run cmake I get an linking error (`undefined reference`)." - Please, show that **exact error message** (add it to the question post). Currently I see that source file `animal.cpp` is **compiled both** to the `animal_lib` and to the `main`. Because you link one with another, you should get "double definition" error instead.

Comment: @Tsyvarev added the error message.

Comment: @JesperJuhl How exactly does the Question you linked to answer my question?

Comment: Which source file defines `something_else_` method? Note to the **terminating undescrore** (`_`); normally such names are not used in the code.

Comment: @Tsyvarev its defines in `animal.hpp`. I've put the underscore there when defining the variable `something_else_` since it is a private member of a class..

Comment: @Sito It tells you what an "undefined reference" *is* and how to fix it by actually linking in the (object file or library) bits that *define* the missing function.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I understood that, my main issue is how I'm supposed to do this in the above example with cmake.

Comment: @Sito fair enough. I re-opened the question.

Comment: @Sito Please show the definition and the declaration for `something_else_`. Tsyvarev is right, it should yield a different error if you had two definitions of a method. But right now it sounds as you have managed to have only a declaration but no definition for `something_else_` in any of your compilation units.

Comment: "its defines in `animal.hpp`" - The **header** file only **declares** the methods of the class (that is, it contains the signature of the method, but doesn't contain the body of the method inside `{}`). But it is a **source** file (`.cpp`) which should **define** the method: it repeats the function signature and provides its body inside `{}`. Please, show the code which **defines** `something_else_` method. For more information about what declaration and definition are see .e.g [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574407/3440745).